# Scrollable GridLayout in a Boxlayout

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've been at this for hours now, trying every solution I could find on here and trying random things....
I'm trying to build a layout consisting of 3 buttons at the top, then a scroll-able GridLayout or BoxLayout. I just cant figure out whats wrong... I've read on one response "bind the layout's size to adapt itself:" but I'm using screenmanagement and cant figure out how to do that with my code setup

```
<HomeScreen>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1,.1
        orientation: "horizontal"
        Button:
            text:"1"
        Button:
            text:"2"
        Button:
            text:"3"
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint_y: None
            row_default_height: 60
            cols:1

            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is correct, you just need to specify the height of the GridLayout. You can use `height: self.minimum_height`.

Reproducible example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_text = '''

<MyScreenManager>:
    HomeScreen:

<HomeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1,.1
            orientation: "horizontal"
            Button:
                text:"1"
            Button:
                text:"2"
            Button:
                text:"3"
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                row_default_height: 60
                cols:1

                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
                Button:
'''

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I swear I tried that... or something close to that... I think... lol Thank you so much! Now, that line "height: self.minimum_height" thats setting the Grid to be the minimum height needed to house all the buttons correct?

Comment: Yeah that's right. `self.minimum_height` is the minimum height to contain all child widgets inside it. @Lemiwinks

Comment: For anyone wanting a ScrollView that scrolls **horizontally** instead of **vertically**, use `width: self.minimum_width` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like @Ishinomori to recreate the app of @FJSevilla in pure Python3.7.
After a few changes I have done it!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window


class HomeScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Initiate Box Layout and change orientation to vertical
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"

        # Top Bar with Buttons "1", "2" & "3"
        self.top_bar = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1, .1))
        self.top_bar.add_widget(Button(text="1"))
        self.top_bar.add_widget(Button(text="2"))
        self.top_bar.add_widget(Button(text="3"))

        # Create the Gridlayout for the Scroll View and add height bounding
        self.contend_scroll_view = GridLayout(size_hint_y=None, row_default_height=60, cols=1)
        self.contend_scroll_view.bind(minimum_height=self.contend_scroll_view.setter('height'))

        # 30 Dummy Buttons (real data here!)
        for _ in range(30):
            self.contend_scroll_view.add_widget(Button())

        # Add the contend to the Scroll View
        self.scroll_view = ScrollView()
        self.scroll_view.add_widget(self.contend_scroll_view)

        # Add the two Widgets to Home Screen
        self.add_widget(self.top_bar)
        self.add_widget(self.scroll_view)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return HomeScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Only runs if file is executed directly, but not if importet
    MyApp().run()
```